# How should this sentence structure be interpreted?

Tags: meaning

> it will be mandatory for you to provide this information in order for
>   us **to meaningfully be able to respond to your query or provide the
>   information or service that you have requested**.
>   (https://sea.filmbankmedia.com/privacy-notice/)

The bold part is confusing. Does it mean:

> (to meaningfully be able to respond to your query) or (to meaningfully
>   be able to provide ... )

or

> (to meaningfully be able to respond to your query) or (to provide ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear, I agree.

I believe it's trying to say that it won't be able to provide a meaningful response to your query, since I don't think one could *meaningfully* provide the information or service.

However, the sentence could be interpreted either way.